# How to trigger a click event on disabled elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a disabled button, which is enabled after checking "I accept terms and conditions" checkbox.
The problem is that I wanted to trigger an alert, if a user **clicks the disabled button**. How can I do this? If an element is disabled, it looks as "onclick" events are not fired.

The sample of the code:

```
<input id="subm_tc" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" disabled="" value="Log in" name="Submit">

    $("#subm_tc").click(function () {
        if($("#modlgn-tc").is(':checked')){
            alert('checked');
        } else {
            alert('unchecked');
        }
    });
```

If I wrap the  element in div and listen to clicks on that div, it works, but you need to click outside the button.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

**UPDATE.** I've managed to resolve this by adding a fake div over the submit button and listening to events on that div (I also change z-index to -200 to enable clicks on the button itself):

```
<div style="position:relative">
<div id="subm_tc" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 99999;"></div>
<input id="subm_tc" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" disabled="" value="Log in" name="Submit">
</div>
```

Now it works as intended

Comment: Try to use `onmousedown` event for disabled element.

Comment: Browsers are supposed to render disabled buttons in such a way the end user understands clicking on them is worthless. They usually do a pretty good job at it. Maybe your alert is not necessary.

Comment: Stupid people may keep clicking till the end of the day before they realize that they should check "accept terms" box.

Comment: concept is not intuitive to user...if it's disabled why would they clcik on it?

Comment: then don't disable it and use validation to show erros when they do click it

Comment: why do you alert "checked" ?

Comment: alert "checked" is just for testing

Comment: It is not a complicated form, but just a login section. Anyway, adding an abs positioned div seems to the simplest solution - see the update.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My solution was to put the button in a div, which is clickable. when the button is disabled, the div has the width and height of the button, so clicking the button triggers the div. when the button is enabled, the div is shrunk to 0 width 0 height, so the click event registers with the button instead of the div. This code includes some demoing code as well for a toggle button which toggles the enabled/disabled state of the button in question

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6as8b/2/

**HTML**

Click 'Toggle" to make 'Button' enabled or disabled. click it, and see that that one event fires if it is enabled, and another if disabled.

```
<input type=button value='toggle' id='toggle'><BR>
<div style='position:relative'>
    <div id='clickable'></div>
    <input id=theButton type=button disabled value='Button'>
        </div>
    <div id=clicks></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#clickable{
position:absolute;
    width:55px;
    height:25px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clickable').on('click',function () {
        if ($('#theButton:disabled').length>0)
        {
        $('#clicks').append('|Disabled Button Clicked|<br>');
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing and let the button handler do it
            $('#theButton').click();
        }
    });
    $('#theButton').on('click',function() {
        $('#clicks').append('|ENABLED button clicked|<br>');
    });
        $('#toggle').on('click',function() {
       if ($('#theButton:disabled').length>0)
        {
            $('#theButton').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#clickable').css({'width':'0px','height':'0px'});
        }
            else
            {
                $('#theButton').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#clickable').css({'width':'55px','height':'25px'});
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Finally, after testing all these options, I've ended up with the updated solution (see my post) UPDATE. it is very similar to yours and a bit more simple as we play with z-index only to move the clickable div back and forth. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Disabled elements doesn't trigger any mouse events at all, so that's probably a lost cause.

However, when clicking a parent element, the event.target seems to be given correctly, which means this should work :

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {   
    if (e.target.id == 'subm_tc') {
        if($("#modlgn-tc").is(':checked')){
             alert('checked');
        } else {
             alert('unchecked');
        }
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jv2er/1/)

Comment: Thanks, a nice solution, but would adding a abs position div around the button be more simple? See my update.

Comment: Didn't realise _#document_ still received the _click_ event from a _disabled_ `<input>` when the `<input>` itself doesn't see it. +1.

Comment: @user2723490 - that depends on you, if you think adding an element with absolute positioning, and then hiding and showing that element etc. is easier than this event handler, then for you it is.

Comment: Works in Webkit, but apparently not in Firefox!

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function that adds listeners to the *mousedown* and *mouseup* events, and if the targets match your *Node* (i.e. the *mousedown* and following *mouseup* were on your element), then it invokes another function

```
function listenFullClick(elm, fn) {
    var last;
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        last = e.target === elm;
    });
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        if (e.target === elm && last) fn();
    });
};

listenFullClick(
    document.getElementById('foo'), // node to look for
    function () {alert('bar');}     // function to invoke
);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VnjR6/2/)

Answer (score 2):

**2022 Update:** I know this is an old question, but here's an update after evaluating various solutions, including CSS `position:absolute` and `pointer-events:none`

The disadvantage of simulating the disabled look ("Pretend Disable") was that, back then, various browsers presented disabled elements differently. That's not as true today because Chrome, Edge, Firefox, and other modern browsers, implement disabled button inputs (and likely other inputs) with the equivalent of `opacity .5` .

The solution below is inspired by https://css-tricks.com/making-disabled-buttons-more-inclusive which uses the `aria-disabled` attribute in place of the older `disabled` attribute. That article strongly advised against using CSS techniques such as `position:absolute` and `pointer-events:none`, because when disabled, the input (or underlying/overlying element) cannot receive focus preventing the possibility of an automatic tooltip when tabbed to and preventing a screen reader from announcing the element is disabled.

Accessible Rich Internet Applications (ARIA) is a set of attributes that define ways to make web content and web applications (especially those developed with JavaScript) more accessible to people with disabilities.

HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='toggle' value='Toggle'>
<input type='button' id='theButton' value='Button'>
<div id='clicksReport'></div>
```

Plain JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#theButton').onclick = function () {
    if (document.querySelector('#theButton').ariaDisabled)
    {
        // Your disabled button code (if any)
        document.querySelector('#clicksReport').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",'|Disabled Button Clicked|<br>');
    }
        else
    {
        // Your emabled button code
        document.querySelector('#clicksReport').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",'|ENABLED button clicked|<br>');
    }
}

document.querySelector('#toggle').onclick = function() {
   if (document.querySelector('#theButton').ariaDisabled)
    {
        // If not a button input, also remove the readOnly attribute
        var el = document.querySelector('#theButton');
        el.ariaDisabled = null;
        el.style.opacity = null;
    }
        else
    {
        // If not a button input, also set the readOnly attribute
        var el = document.querySelector('#theButton');
        el.ariaDisabled = true;
        el.style.opacity = '.5';
    }
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SKisby/3Lna8q7h/7/

The same in d3 (as that's what I'm currenlty using and it's similar to jQuery):

```
d3.select('#theButton').on('click',function () {
    if (d3.select('#theButton').attr('aria-disabled'))
    {
        // Your disabled button code (if any)
        d3.select('#clicksReport').node().insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",'|Disabled Button Clicked|<br>');
    }
        else
    {
        // Your emabled button code
        d3.select('#clicksReport').node().insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",'|ENABLED button clicked|<br>');
    }
});

d3.select('#toggle').on('click',function() {
   if (d3.select('#theButton').attr('aria-disabled'))
    {
        // If not a button input, also remove the readOnly attribute
        d3.select('#theButton').attr('aria-disabled',null)
        .style('opacity',null);
    }
        else
    {
        // If not a button input, also set the readOnly attribute
        d3.select('#theButton').attr('aria-disabled',true)
        .style('opacity','.5');
    }
});
```

d3 Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SKisby/qkvf3opL/2/

The above are simple, both have the same disabled look in Chrome, Firefox, and other modern browsers, and have the benefits of being able to receive focus (where an automatic tooltip could then be implemented and ARIA screen readers can convey the element is effectively disabled).

If the input is not a button, also set and remove the `readOnly` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but here are my two cents as I had the same challenge lately:

Don't try to position a clickable element above it but wrap it with one so you won’t directly be able to click it. Assuming a button with `display: inline-block` set:

```html
<span class="on-disabled">
  <input id="subm_tc" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" disabled value="Log in" name="Submit">
</span>
```

Define you click event for the case of the button being disabled:

```js
$('.on-disabled').click(function (ev) {
  // Don’t react to click events bubbling up
  if (ev.target !== ev.currentTarget) return;
  // Do your thing
  alert('Sorry, this button is disabled');
});
```

And simply style the button like:

```css
#subm_tc {
  display: inline-block;
}

#subm_tc[disabled] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

This allows you to easily react to a click even in case of a disabled button.
See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6w1t3vz5/9/).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Twitter Bootstrap, they give you a class `disabled` that provides the styling but doesn't remove the `click` event. Given that, what I did was this (keep in mind also, I wanted to be sure that when the button was no longer disabled, the original click event did fire, and I didn't want to deal with unbinding, rebinding it).

```
function disableButton(btn, message) {
  btn.addClass("disabled")
  if (!(message == null || message == "")) {
    btn.data("message", message)
  }
}

function enableButton(btn) {
  btn.removeClass("disabled")
}

$("#btn").click(function() {
  if (!($(this).hasClass("disabled"))) {
    // original, desired action
  } else {
    message = $(this).data("message")
    if (!(message == null || message == "")) {
      alert(message)
    }
  }
```

})