# How to disable <select> tag, but at the same time binding jquery click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just noticed a weird behavior:

I want to dynamically disable a  element to prevent a user to open the options menu, but at the same time I want to bind a click, so the user when clicks it, it will receive an alert "sorry this selector is disabled"

a better example can be, say, when you have two select elements, and if the user chooses an option from #select1, it's forbidden to choose anything form #select2

I don't want to hide the #select2 for other reason I don't need to fully explain.

```
<form>
   <select id="select1" disabled> // jquery on() won't work because of "disable"
        <option value='1' >apple</option>
        <option value='2' >banana</option>
    </select>
</form>


 $('form').on('click', '#select1', function(e){
        // do something
 });
```

Comment: Build a working snippet, please.

Comment: Maybe a div around it that receives the click?

Comment: @Luca maybe... I was hoping to avoid extra elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, other examples of Q / A on this same topic:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294867/how-to-trigger-a-click-event-on-disabled-elements?rq=1  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833854/jquery-detect-click-on-disabled-submit-button and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109228/clicking-a-disabled-input-or-button/16109366

Comment: You can wrap your form in a `DIV` and use the event on the `DIV`.

Comment: Thanks @cale_b I will look into those articles

Comment: A label around the select, rather than a div, might be more semantic.

Comment: you could write this a lot cleaner in vanilla js, you could have a click event and a variable to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to a disabled field in javascript. Your options would be to make a div around the select to receive the click events as mentioned by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51213479/10043162), or if you really don't want additional elements, you can leave the select box enabled, style it to look disabled, and immediately blur on click. This isn't a very clean solution but I don't know what your restrictions are as far as adding elements goes.

```js
$("#select1").click(function(){
 $(this).blur();
});
```

```css
.disabled{
  color: #bababa;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="select1" class="disabled">
      <option value='1' >apple</option>
      <option value='2' >banana</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround solution to your problem.

You can overlay a `div` over the select and upon loading, check if it `disabled` if it is *NOT* `disabled`, we use `.remove()` to remove the overlay, otherwise,  we keep it there to hook a `.on('click'...)` event onto it.

---

```js
let disabled = $('#select1').is(':disabled')

if (!disabled) {
  $('#test').remove();
}

$('#test').on('click', function(e) {
  alert("sorry this selector is disabled");
});
```

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 68px;
  height: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <select id="select1" disabled>
    <option value='1'>apple</option>
    <option value='2'>banana</option>
  </select>
</form>
```