# how to fire click event for disabled dropdown in gridview in javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to fire click event for disabled dropdown for this  $("#AdditionalInfo").find("tr").find('#ddlLineDBItem_AddGrdInfo').attr('disabled', 'disabled') in javascript and click event is not firing for disabled dropdown in gridview

$("#AdditionalInfo").find("tr").eq(cnt - 2).find('#ddlLineDBItem_AddGrdInfo').attr('disabled', 'disabled').on('click', function () {
// Code to be executed on mouseover
gd_open_pop(this, 'divInfoLinePopupAdditional', 'c', 'bl', 'EditLineItemSpecilist', GridID, '');
$(this).css('background-color', 'lightgray');
// Example: Change background color on mouseover
})

```
            .mouseout(function () {
                // Code to be executed on mouseout           
                $(this).css('background-color', '');
                // Example: Reset background color on mouseout   
        and click event is not firing
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294867/how-to-trigger-a-click-event-on-disabled-elements

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled#

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a click event on disabled elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294867/how-to-trigger-a-click-event-on-disabled-elements)