How to capture click event by parent element when a child element disabled?
I want to capture click event by parent element when a child element disabled (button, input or other elements can be disabled), like this codes


document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('clicked!')
  // both two ways to stop propagation are useless
  event.stopImmediatePropagation()
  event.stopPropagation()
}, { capture: true })
<div>
  <button disabled>button</button>
</div>



When I click this button, the event will not be captured by div (standard), but I want this div to capture this event. How can I do this?

pointer-events:none does not work for me because I need to use document.elementsFromPoint() to get this button and do something. And pointer-events:none will cause the button to not be retrieved by this function


The best way will be to follow the accepted answer of this SO answer by chiliNUT

@Mehdi So far, it seems that you are right

We could give the button an overlay and remove it when enabled


document.getElementById('overlay').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Handle the event as if the disabled button was clicked
  console.log('Overlay clicked, handling as if the disabled button was clicked.');
});
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

/* Hide overlay when button is not disabled */
#myButton:not(:disabled)~#overlay {
  display: none;
}
<div id="parentDiv" style="position: relative;">
  <button id="myButton" disabled>Disabled Button</button>
  <!-- Transparent overlay -->
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>




Read carefully the Q: OP mentioned something about elementsFromPoint(). Using an overlay DIV defies the thing. (PS, thinking about that once again, is elementsFromPoint() even able to detect a disabled button?... in such case OP's Q would be an XY-PRoblem)

Seems my suggestion is close to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294867/how-to-trigger-a-click-event-on-disabled-elements

@Roko C. Buljan elementsFromPoint can detect a disabled button(you can try that by mousemove event which can be captured when the button disabled)

@肉蛋充肌 Yes, I tested and realized that, and added an answer that even incorporates it since really helpful in detecting the actual button!.

There seems to be no better way to do it at the moment.


Important: create a child element like <span> inside the disabled button
Important: remove any default stylings from button using appearance: none; padding: 0; so that the child SPAN's area can fully catch the pointer
Assign a click listener to that SPANs selector: "button[disabled] > span" that will in return emulate a .click() on the parent DIV
To further detect the actual button, use elementsFromPoint(x, y) and find in the returned array the BUTTON Element

Example:


const div = document.querySelector("div");
div.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  console.log("DIV CLICKED!"); // Works thanks to child SPAN emulating a DIV click
  // You can stop here. DIV finally registers the click.

  // If you want to further detect if a button was clicked
  // and get that actual button Element, use:
  const {clientX:x, clientY:y} = evt;
  const btn = document.elementsFromPoint(x, y).find(el => el.tagName === "BUTTON");
  if (btn) {
    console.log(btn);
  }
});

const spans = div.querySelectorAll("button[disabled] > span");
spans.forEach(btnSpan => {
  // Necessary since the DISABLED button prevents from propagating the Event
  btnSpan.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    div.click();
  });
});
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

button {
  appearance: none;
  padding: 0;
}

button span {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
<div>
  <button disabled><span>Disabled with SPAN</span></button>
  <br>
  <button><span>Not Disabled with SPAN</span></button>
</div>



If you cannot edit the HTML directly (for some reason) in order to insert the SPANs inside your BUTTONs, you can always use JavaScript:


document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((btn) => {
  const text = btn.firstChild; // {#text}
  const span = Object.assign(document.createElement("span"), {
    textContent: text.nodeValue
  });
  text.replaceWith(span);
});
button {
  appearance: none;
  padding: 0;
}
button > span {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  color: red;
}
<p>Example dynamically inserting SPAN into BUTTONs</p>
<button disabled>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>




This is a viable option, but it doesn't work in my scenario. 1. For buttons, it's doable! However, if it's a disabled input, it doesn't seem feasible to do so. 2. In my scenario I have to add a click event to the outermost div and get the corresponding element via elementsFromPoint(), so adding an extra event to a single span doesn't work for me

@肉蛋充肌 I missed that part where you mention INPUT, TEXTAREA, etc, Sorry - The answer is then "No". Not possible. I can eventually try some other ideas, but I think I'll lose the battle with the [disabled] attribute I'm afraid.

You may want to define your own way to disable a button. Using a class and reacting to it in the click event listener will still send the event to the parent.
This means that you would disable a button by adding a disabled class to the button rather than using the disabled attribute.


for(var div of document.querySelectorAll('div')) {
 div.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('The parent was clicked.');
 }, true);
}

for(var button of document.querySelectorAll('button')) {
 button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(this.classList.contains('disabled')) {
   console.log('The disabled button was clicked.');
  } else {
   console.log('The button was clicked.');
  }
 });
}
button {
 appearance: none;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 2px;
 background: #E8E8E8;
 color: #CCC;
 &:not(.disabled, [disabled]) {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
   background: #E0E0E0;
  }
  &:active {
   background: #F0F0F0;
  }
 }
}
<div>
 <button>Enabled Button</button>
 <button class='disabled'>My Button</button>
 <button disabled>Disabled Button></button>
</div>




That's a last choice because my button( and other basic components) is from a third part component library. But thanks for the actionable advice
